# String from TableView JavaFx is returning Memory Address instead of The Value in ObserveList

Tags: java, string, javafx

I am trying to retrieve the Value that is inside of a tableView JavaFx GUI. The data is from my database and I need to retrieve that data as a String in order to send it to a method and update the database.

Here is the code I have for the tableView connected to the GUI I am having problems getting the String value from.

```
public class YourFlights  {

    static Stage window;
    static TableView table;
    static TextField nameInput;
    static TextField arrInput;
    static TextField depInput;
    private ReservationDataAccessor dataAccessor;
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    int userId = MainPage.userId;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        dataAccessor = new ReservationDataAccessor("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo", "flightuser",
                "flightuser");
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Your Flights");


     // Flight column
            TableColumn<Flight, String> flightIDColumn = new TableColumn<>("flight ID");
            flightIDColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightNumber"));
            flightIDColumn.setMinWidth(200);

            // Arrival_Date Column
            TableColumn<Flight, String> departingCityColumn = new TableColumn<>("Departing City");
            departingCityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("departureCity"));
            departingCityColumn.setMinWidth(200);

            // Departure_Date Column
            TableColumn<Flight, String> arrivalCityColumn = new TableColumn<>("Arrival City");
            arrivalCityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("arrivalCity"));
            arrivalCityColumn.setMinWidth(200);

            // Departure City Column
            TableColumn<Flight, String> departureTimeColumn = new TableColumn<>("Departure Time");
            departureTimeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("timeOfDeparture"));
            departureTimeColumn.setMinWidth(200);

            // Arrival_Date Column
            TableColumn<Flight, String> arrivalTimeColumn = new TableColumn<>("Arrival Time");
            arrivalTimeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("timeOfArrival"));
            arrivalTimeColumn.setMinWidth(200);

            // Arrival_Date Column
            TableColumn<Flight, String> flightDateColumn = new TableColumn<>("Flight Date");
            flightDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightDate"));
            flightDateColumn.setMinWidth(200);




        //Name input
        nameInput = new TextField();
        nameInput.setPromptText("Name");
        nameInput.setMinWidth(100);

        //departure input
        arrInput = new TextField();
        arrInput.setPromptText("Arr");

        //departure input
        depInput = new TextField();
        depInput.setPromptText("Dep");

        //Button
        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        //addButton.setOnAction(e -> addButtonClicked());
        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
        deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> deleteButtonClicked());

        Button btn = new Button("Go Back");

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(nameInput, arrInput, depInput, addButton, deleteButton, btn);

        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            MainPage m2 = new MainPage();
            try {
                m2.start(primaryStage);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().addAll(flightIDColumn, departingCityColumn, arrivalCityColumn, departureTimeColumn,
                arrivalTimeColumn, flightDateColumn);
        table.setItems(getFlight());

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(table, hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    public ObservableList<Flight> getFlight() throws SQLException {
        ObservableList<Flight> flights = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        flights.addAll(dataAccessor.getAllReservationList(userId));
        return flights;
    }



   // Delete button clicked
    public static void deleteButtonClicked(){
        ObservableList<Flight> flightSelected, allFlights;
        allFlights = table.getItems();
        flightSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        flightSelected.forEach(allFlights                   ::remove);
       try {
          String listString =  table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().toString();
            System.out.println(listString);
        ReservationDataAccessor.deleteReservation(Integer.parseInt(listString));


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}



/*    //Add button clicked
    public static void addButtonClicked(){
        Flight flight = new Flight();
        flight.setName(nameInput.getText());
        flight.setArr(arrInput.getText());
        flight.setDep(depInput.getText());
        table.getItems().add(flight);
        nameInput.clear();
        arrInput.clear();
        depInput.clear();
    }
*/
```

This is the specific code I am using to try and get a String from the Table then turn that String into an Integer and send it to the method. Problem is that the String only points to an address and doesn't give me the values I want which are basically just Numbers inside of Strings. or just numbers not sure.

```
   public static void deleteButtonClicked(){
        ObservableList<Flight> flightSelected, allFlights;
        allFlights = table.getItems();
        flightSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        flightSelected.forEach(allFlights                   ::remove);
       try {
          String listString =  table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().toString();
            System.out.println(listString);
        ReservationDataAccessor.deleteReservation(Integer.parseInt(listString));


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

This is the code that is used as the Data Accessor Object. It runs methods to pull and insert into the database.

```
public class ReservationDataAccessor {

     static int userId = MainPage.userId;

    private static Connection connection;
    private String myQuery = null;

    public ReservationDataAccessor(String driverClassName, String dbURL, String user, String password)
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(driverClassName);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, password);
    }

    public void shutdown() throws SQLException {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }

    // gets all of user's reservation
    public List<Reservation> getAllReservationList(int userId) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement stmnt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(
                        "Select Reservation.FlightId, departingCity, arrivalCity, arrivalTime, departureTime, flightDate from \n"
                                + "Reservation inner join Flight on Reservation.Flightid = Flight.FlightId where customerId ="
                                + userId);) {
            List<Reservation> allReservationsList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String flightId = rs.getString("flightId");
                String flightDate = rs.getString("flightDate");
                String timeOfDeparture = rs.getString("departureTime");
                String timeOfArrival = rs.getString("arrivalTime");
                String departureCity = rs.getString("departingCity");
                String arrivalCity = rs.getString("arrivalCity");
                Reservation reservation = new Reservation(flightId, flightDate, timeOfDeparture, timeOfArrival,
                        departureCity, arrivalCity);
                allReservationsList.add(reservation);
            }
            return allReservationsList;
        }
    }

    // adds reservations
    //needs to be modified and tested
    public static String addReservation(String flightNumber) throws SQLException {

        String query = " INSERT INTO Reservation (FlightID, CustomerId) VALUES (?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    //  preparedStmt.setString(1, reservationId);
        preparedStmt.setInt(0, Integer.parseInt(flightNumber));
        preparedStmt.setInt(1, userId);
        preparedStmt.execute();
        connection.close();

    //  Reservation reservation = new Reservation(flightNumber, userId);
        return flightNumber;
    }

    // delete reservations
    //needs to be modified and tested
        public static int deleteReservation(int flightId) throws SQLException {

            String query = "DELETE Reservation FROM Reservation WHERE FlightID= '?' AND CustomerID= '?'";
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setInt(0, flightId);
            preparedStmt.setInt(1, userId);
            preparedStmt.execute();
            connection.close();

            return flightId;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect the `toString` result of a list to be parseable as a single integer. Why do you even want to convert it to string and parse the string instead of accessing the properties of the elements of the `ObservableList<Flight>`?

Comment: So you saying its an easier to access the properties directly? I just need to be able to pull the data from the table or observe list. Whichever way I can.